# How do background color of UITableView section scrollBar make clear?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

I want to make the scrollbar's background color clear, but I cannot find the property for it.
Just help me.

Comment: you can simply hide the scroll bar.

Comment: Did you set `opaque` property to `NO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you coloring the cells?  It looks like the `contentView` of the cell is being adjusted to fit the section index view.  Try setting a `backgroundView` on the table cell with your background color.

Comment: right, I changed the background color of contentView. I guess that's the problem, but changing the background color of backgroundView doesn't work! Cell's background color is still white...

Comment: Did you make sure to init a new `UIView` first?  The property is `nil` by default.  Try `cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init]; cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];`

Comment: Solved! Reeeeeally Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set UITableView background view as nil to make it transparent.

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Hope it helps you.